# css clip-path : url (); not working with svg file source

Tags: css, svg

i have a svg file exported from adobe illustrator and i tried to use it to shape my layer like we did with clip-path : polygon(); but its not working anyway and here is my code

```css
.he-b {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(svg/Asset1.svg);
  clip-path: url(svg/Asset1.svg);
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 78.24 90.35">
 <defs>
  <style>
   .cls-1{
    fill:#231f20;
   }
  </style>
 </defs>
 <title>
  Asset 1
 </title>
 <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
  <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
   <path class="cls-1" d="M39.12,0,0,22.59V67.76L39.12,90.35,78.24,67.76V22.59ZM65.88,60.63,39.12,76.08,12.36,60.63V29.72L39.12,14.27,65.88,29.72Z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: An entire svg file cannot be a clip-path. You need to point to the id of a clipPath element within the file.

Comment: i Tried it but it's not seems to be working

Comment: tried it how? Update your question.

Comment: `-webkit-clip-path: url(svg/Asset1.svg#Layer_2);
  clip-path: url(svg/Asset1.svg#Layer_2);`

Comment: and tried this`-webkit-clip-path: url(svg/Asset1.svg#Layer_1-2);
  clip-path: url(svg/Asset1.svg#Layer_1-2);`

Comment: A g element cannot be the target of a clipPath

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clip-path for internal and external SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941575/clip-path-for-internal-and-external-svg)

Answer (score 0):

check this.

1. This type property works on Firefox not chrome.
   "xxx.svg#id"
2. Svg clipPath tag format is not on your sample.

#I think css propery is ok.

some sample ?
see below
[using an external svg with clip-path in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824452/using-an-external-svg-with-clip-path-in-firefox)
[Clip-path for internal and external SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941575/clip-path-for-internal-and-external-svg) > jsfiddle.net/stjtudvj/2

Comment: When you come across a question that was already asked, please flag it as duplicate, no need to answer with links

Comment: @Vega Users can't flag posts until they get 15 rep.